# SignalR not working on local IIS but working with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to write a small SignalR project. When the project is set to run under IIS Express everything works as it should.

But when in Visual Studio project properties I switch to "Local IIS" and try to run, my page loads and does not connect to the SignalR Server.

I've checked with Fiddler and I found that while all script are loaded correctly relative to the path, the SignalR calls are made to the root of the website. So in fiddler I see something like this:

```
3   304 HTTP    localhost   /TestApp/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js   0           microsoftedgecp:11004           
4   304 HTTP    localhost   /TestApp/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js    0           microsoftedgecp:11004           
6   404 HTTP    localhost   /signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22testapphub%22%7D%5D&_=1440092162315  4,958   private text/html; charset=utf-8    microsoftedgecp:11004
```

As you can see, the SignalR is calling it's negotiate on `/signalr` while the project is running under `/TestApp/`

How can I tell it to look at to correct location (relative) ?

**Edit**

This is my `OwinStartup.cs`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

I have nothing defined in global.asax - should I?

Comment: Can you show us the startup file where you do your configuration? You also need a call to MapHubs in your Global.asax -is that there?

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson I've added the info above. I don't have anything defined in my global.asax - should I?

Comment: What kind of web application are you running? Is it an empty web app, MVC, WebAPI?

Comment: @Matei_Radu normal asp.net web app. no mvc.

Comment: Could you please provide the client connection code? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, forget that comment about Global.asax; looks like I found a resource for the 1.2 version. The solution below should point you in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something that makes it work. It doesn't have to do with mapping in the OwinStartup (which after testing I found that is being called but not braked during debug).

After digging inside the js source file of SignalR I found this function the initializes a hub connection:

```
function hubConnection(url, options) {
    /// <summary>Creates a new hub connection.</summary>
    /// <param name="url" type="String">[Optional] The hub route url, defaults to "/signalr".</param>
    /// <param name="options" type="Object">[Optional] Settings to use when creating the hubConnection.</param>
    var settings = {
        qs: null,
        logging: false,
        useDefaultPath: true
    };

    $.extend(settings, options);

    if (!url || settings.useDefaultPath) {
        url = (url || "") + "/signalr";
    }
    return new hubConnection.fn.init(url, settings);
}
```

As you can see, it takes a url parameter. So when I initialized my hub with the following code:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('/TestApp/');
```

It now works. Now I just wrote a simple server side that checks weather it should initialize this parameter (if it's running in a sub-directory) and inject the value to the HTML page.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from developer82 didn't quite work for me, but I don't have enough points to comment so I'm submitting it as a separate answer. I needed to specify my connection like this:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('/TestApp/signalr');
```

where TestApp is the virtual directory name. Note that I explicitly had to tack signalr on to the end.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when switching to Local IIS. 
After upgrading to to signalR-2.2.0 via 'Manage NuGet Packages' I did read this readme.txt:

> Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=272764 for more
>   information on using SignalR.
>
> **Upgrading from 1.x to 2.0**
>   Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 for more information on
>   how to  upgrade your SignalR 1.x application to 2.0.
>
> **Mapping the Hubs connection**
>   To enable SignalR in your application, create a class called Startup with the following:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.Owin;
> using Owin; 
> using MyWebApplication;
>
> namespace MyWebApplication {
>   public class Startup
>   {
>       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>       {
>           app.MapSignalR();
>       }
>   }   
> }
> ```
>
> **Getting Started**
>   See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started for more
>   information on how to get started.
>
> **Why does ~/signalr/hubs return 404 or Why do I get a JavaScript error:**
>   **'myhub is undefined'?**
>   This issue is generally due to a missing or invalid script reference
>   to the auto-generated Hub JavaScript proxy at '~/signalr/hubs'. Please
>   make sure that the Hub route is registered before any other routes in
>   your application.
>   
> **In ASP.NET MVC 4** you can do the following:
>
> ```
>   <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
> ```
>
> If you're writing an **ASP.NET MVC 3** application, make sure that you are using Url.Content
>   for your script references:
>
> ```
> <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
> ```
>
> If you're writing a **regular ASP.NET** application use ResolveClientUrl for your
>   script references or register them via the ScriptManager  using a app
>   root relative path (starting with a '~/'):
>
> ```
> <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
> ```
>
> If the above still doesn't work, you may have an issue with routing
>   and extensionless URLs. To fix this, ensure you have the latest 
>   patches installed for IIS and ASP.NET.

Since I am working on a regular ASP.NET application, I had to change this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js") %'></script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

Previously I added a class file "Startup.SignalR.cs":

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            ConfigureSignalR(app);
            ConfigureAuth(app);            
        }
    }
}
```

Now in Project / Properties I can switch between IIS Express and Local ISS (for debugging / production).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

        app.MapSignalR("/TestApp", hubConfiguration);
    }
```

Now, that should tell your application to map the SignalR process to your /TestApp physical location. In my experience, using the straight `app.MapSignalR();` works about 30% of the time, and the rest, I have to use an explicit location declaration like the above.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried debugging and I notice that under IIS OwinStartup is not being called.

Comment: Is the package `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` in your project? It looks like IIS [needs that](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) to detect Startup.

Comment: And the app pool your application is trying to run under is integrated, not classic?

Comment: It is. I searched online - that's what all the answers to the same problem suggest to check - but still doesn't work :(

Comment: And your startup class is an OWIN startup class which you created through the VS Create-New dialog?

Comment: Huh. Well, you've got me. Can you get one of those simple test apps to run on IIS?

Comment: I've put a logger inside the OwinStart class and the logger writes to log file - so it seems that the class is being called but can't be braked into while debugging. I put your command in, still it's looking for SignalR in the root.